# Ubuntu 20.04 not booting with /dev/nvme0n1p7:clean

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

I have a dual boot in my computer and I was using it for some time but now after a message that I ignored for full memory in ubuntu I can not boot the ubuntu part. After I select ubuntu to boot a get a black screen with the message `/dev/nvme0n1p7:clean xxx/xxx files xxx/xxx blocks`. I already tried the boot-repair proposed in some other questions and I got the following [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/j5wpnQJ8Kb/). I also managed to erased 1.5GB of files from the disk in question but that didn't seem to solve the problem. Thank you in advance for any effort.

Answer (score 0):

Boot with a live Linux USB, in Terminal on it.

```
sudo fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1p7
```

You have file system corruption that needs to be fixed on the install partition, that is what that error is telling you.

Comment: and how do I fix this corruption?

Comment: Run the command given in a Terminal booted with a Linux live USB stick, may as well be the one you installed the machine with. Since in my experience you can get a Terminal with most any of them.